# Fiddler not capturing outbound requests from Apache Server

Tags: apache, request, fiddler

I am using Fiddler to get all traffic on an Apache server. The problem is that Fiddler captures every thing except HTTP Requests from Apache sent with Zend_HTTP_Client. What should I do?

Comment: What is your application dev env? aka language framework etc ?

Comment: @OmidKosari PHP , Zend Framework , Xampp . I`m using zend_http_client!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $config = array(
    'adapter'       => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',
    'proxy_host'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'proxy_port'    => 8888,
    'timeout'       => 60,
    'useragent'     => 'Test',
    'keepalive'     => true,
    'sslusecontext' => true
);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://www.site.com/',  $config);
```